# Importing GCM to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

After I import `GCM` to `Firebase`, what happens to my old `Google Console GCM` project? Does it go away?

We want to come up with a contingency plan if something goes wrong with `Firebase` and we need to rollback to `GCM` for sending out notification messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a project into Firebase, all that really does is add Firebase services to that project, and you see it listed along with other Firebase-enabled projects in the Firebase console.  Nothing should change in that project that already exists at the time of import, so you should be able to safely continue whatever you were doing there.